# Proving that if $AB=A$ and $BA=B$, then both matrices are idempotent

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, idempotents

Let $A, B$ be two matrices such that $AB=A$ and $BA=B$, how do I show that $A\cdot A=A$ and $B\cdot B=B$?

Steps I took:

1. Let $A= \left[\begin{array}{rr} 
       a & b \\
       c & d \\
      \end{array}\right]$ and let $B= \left[\begin{array}{rr} 
       w & x \\
       y & z \\
      \end{array}\right]$
2. $\left[\begin{array}{rr} 
       a & b \\
       c & d \\
      \end{array}\right] \cdot \left[\begin{array}{rr} 
       w & x \\
       y & z \\
      \end{array}\right] = \left[\begin{array}{rr} 
       aw+by & ax+bz \\
       cw+dy & cx+dz \\
      \end{array}\right] $ (Which is also equal to A)
3. $\left[\begin{array}{rr} 
       w & x \\
       y & z \\ 
      \end{array}\right] \cdot \left[\begin{array}{rr} 
       a & b \\
       c & d \\
      \end{array}\right] = \left[\begin{array}{rr} 
       wa+xc & wb+xd \\
       ya+zc & yb+zd \\
      \end{array}\right] $ (Which is also equal to B)

At this point I am stuck. I don't know how to proceed and I imagine that I started off on the wrong track to begin with. I'd like a hint to guide me in the right direction.

---

My proof after consultation with answerers below:

Proof:

1) Since $AB=A$, we can say that: $(AB)A=AA$ which is equal to $A^2$

2) Then, (by associativity of matrix multiplication), we can say that $A(BA) = AB$ (since $BA=B$)

3) Then, $AB=A$ (since $AB=A$ was given)

4) Therefore, $AA$ is equal to $A$

5) Since $BA=B$, we can also say that: $(BA)B=BB$ which is equal to $B^2$

6) Then, (by associativity of matrix multiplication) we can say that $B(AB)=BA$ (since $AB=A$)

7) Then, $BA=B$

8) Therefore, $BB$ is equal to $B$

9) Thus, $AA$ is equal to $A$ and $BB$ is equal to $B$

Q.E.D.

Comment: Are you assuming they're $2 \times 2$ matrices?

Comment: @MarcusM Yes, I am. Is that wrong?

Comment: @Cherry_Developer Well, it is not sufficient to look at the case of $2\times 2$ matrices if you want to prove something for general matrices. If you want to prove a statement of $2\times 2$ matrices, then it is not wrong.

Comment: This is not a good way to solve the exercise. The only thing you need is associativity of matrix product.

Comment: One comment on the edit: associativity allows us to say $A(B)A = A(BA)$ or $(BA)B = B(AB)$. It is *transitivity of equality* that then allows us to say $AA = (AB)A = A(BA) = AB = A$, or $BB = B(AB) = B(AB) = BA = B$. So you're "combining steps" at step 2) and 6),

Comment: @DavidWheeler Can you clarify what you mean by: ' "combining steps" at step 2) and 6) '

Comment: Well, for example, instead of $A(BA) = AB$ at step 2) it should say: $(AB)A = (AB)A$ (by associativity), and then: $A(BA) = AB$ (since $BA = B$) at say, step 2a).

Comment: @DavidWheeler $(AB)A = (AB)A$ ? Why would I write that?

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo-I meant to write $A(BA) = (AB)A$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $AB = A$, and $BA = B$, then:

$A^2 = AA = (AB)A$ (since we can replace $A$ with $AB$ since they are equal)

$= A(BA)$ (by associativity of matrix multiplication)

$ = AB$ (since $BA = B$)

$= A$ (since $AB = A$).

Now you can try to use the same reasoning to prove $B^2 = B$.

This works for any two $n \times n$ matrices, $A,B$ that satisfy $AB = A$ and $BA = B$, not just $2 \times 2$ matrices.

Comment: I wrote up the proof. Would you be willing to look it over for me?

Comment: @Cherry_Developer you are always welcome to post your own answer to a question here, even when it's *your* question. This happens a lot, actually.

Comment: Would you be willing to look it over though?

Comment: Sure, i don't see why not.

Comment: I added it to my original post. Please look it over, if you can. Let me know what you think.

Answer (score 10):

Notice that $AA = (AB)(AB) = A(BA)B = ABB = AB = A$.

Comment: As noted in the comments above, associativity of the matrix product is *crucial*. From my vantage point, I immediately see the truth, here, but a beginner might not understand why we can play fast and loose with the parentheses.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Start with $AA = (AB)A$ (because of the first equality)

Answer (score 1):

$$A \cdot B = A \\
\implies (A \cdot B) \cdot A
= A \cdot A \\
\implies A \cdot (B \cdot A) = A^2 \\
\implies A \cdot B = A^2 = A$$

Answer (score -3):

Since $AB=A$ and $BA=B$, to show that $A$ is an idempotent we have to show that $A=A^2$
Therefore $A^2=(AB)^2 = A^2B^{ } = AB = A(BA) = AA = A^2 = A$. Proven

Comment: I don't think this really tracks, since $A$ and $B$ need not commute and it's unclear whatthe justification for the third equality is